# How to get list of strings from json object

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

I have the following JSON:

```
{"errors":[{"code":888,"errorId":"xxx","message":"String value expected","fields":["name", "address"]}, {}, {}]}
```

I want to be able to get "fields" the following way:

```
public static String getField(json, errorsIndex, fieldIndex) {
    JSONObject errorJson = json.getJSONArray("errors").getJSONObject(errorIndex);
    String value = errorJson.[getTheListOfMyFields].get(fieldIndex);
    return value;
}
```

But I can't find a way to make this part [getTheListOfMyFields]. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `getTheListOfMyFields` supposed to be an index?

Comment: no, just a list of strings(List<String>): ["name", "address"]

Comment: At the end, you want `value` to be the element in the "fields" array at index `fieldIndex`, is that correct? So for example, if `fieldIndex` were 1, then `value` would be "address"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of getting a `List<String>` from the JSON Object, you can access the array of fields in the same way you are accessing the array of errors:

```
public static String getField(JSONObject json, String errorsIndex, String fieldIndex) {
    JSONObject errorJson = json.getJSONArray("errors").getJSONObject(errorIndex);
    String value = errorJson.getJSONArray("fields").getString(fieldIndex);
    return value;
}
```

Note that `get(fieldIndex)` has changed to `getString(fieldIndex)`. That way you don't have to cast an Object to a String.

Comment: I thought JSONArray is an aray of json objects and it it not applicable here... haha =) Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: What the type of 'json' parameter, ha?

Comment: @DynoCris It's a `JSONObject` from the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) package.